# How to link 'from outside' into Navigator (for example from a global footer)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

With [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org), is there a way to link *from outside* to a specific path/screen inside a Navigator?

For example to implement a global footer, like this:

```js
<Provider store={store}>
  <View>
     <AppNavigator />
     <MyFooter /> // Link from here to a path/screen inside AppNavigator
  </View>
</Provider>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `refs` might work here. If you want to use Navigator from the same level you declare it you can use react's `refs` and pass `props` to `MyFooter`. Look at [example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/#Calling-Navigate-on-Top-Level-Component) in official documentation.

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(SomeAppRouteConfigs);

class App extends React.Component {
  someFunction = () => {
    // call navigate for AppNavigator here:
    this.navigator && this.navigator.dispatch({ type: 'Navigate', routeName, params });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <AppNavigator ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }} />
        <MyFooter someFunction={this.someFunction} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, I have no navigator object outside AppNavigator, otherwise I could just use `navigation.navigate` inside the Footer directly.

Comment: But you can access AppNavigator via refs just like in example.

Comment: You are of course completely right, thanks & have an upvote!

Answer (score 3):

Go to this link:
 https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

## React Navigation Version: 5.x

Sometimes you need to trigger a navigation action from places where you do not have access to the `navigation` prop, such as a Redux middleware. For such cases, you can dispatch navigation actions from the navigation container.

If you're looking for a way to navigate from inside a component without needing to pass the `navigation` prop down, see `useNavigation`.

You can get access to the root navigation object through a `ref` and pass it to the `RootNavigation` which we will later use to navigate.

```js
// App.js

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

In the next step, we define `RootNavigation`, which is a simple module with functions that dispatch user-defined navigation actions.

```js
// RootNavigation.js

import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them
```

Then, in any of your javascript modules, just import the `RootNavigation` and call functions which you exported from it. You may use this approach outside of your React components and, in fact, it works just as well when used from within them.

```js
// any js module
import * as RootNavigation from './path/to/RootNavigation.js';

// ...

RootNavigation.navigate('ChatScreen', { userName: 'Lucy' });
```

Apart from `navigate`, you can add other navigation actions:

```js
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

export function push(...args) {
  navigationRef.current?.dispatch(StackActions.push(...args));
}
```

Note that a stack navigators needs to be rendered to handle this action. You may want to check the [docs for nesting](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators.html#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator) for more details.

When writing tests, you may mock the navigation functions, and make assertions on whether the correct functions are called with the correct parameters.

### Handling initialization

When using this pattern, you need to keep few things in mind to avoid crashes in your app.

- The ref is set only after the navigation container renders
- A navigator needs to be rendered to be able to handle actions

If you try to navigate without rendering a navigator or before the navigator finishes mounting, it will throw and crash your app if not handled. So you'll need to add an additional check to decide what to do until your app mounts.

For an example, consider the following scenario, you have a screen somewhere in the app, and that screen dispatches a redux action on `useEffect`/`componentDidMount`. You are listening for this action in your middleware and try to perform navigation when you get it. This will throw an error, because by this time, the parent navigator hasn't finished mounting. Parent's `useEffect`/`componentDidMount` is always called **after** child's `useEffect`/`componentDidMount`.

To avoid this, you can set a ref to tell you that your app has finished mounting, and check that ref before performing any navigation. To do this, we can use `useEffect` in our root component:

```js
// App.js

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef, isMountedRef } from './RootNavigation';

export default function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    isMountedRef.current = true;

    return () => (isMountedRef.current = false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Also export this ref from our `RootNavigation`:

```js
// RootNavigation.js

import * as React from 'react';

export const isMountedRef = React.createRef();

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  if (isMountedRef.current && navigationRef.current) {
    // Perform navigation if the app has mounted
    navigationRef.current.navigate(name, params);
  } else {
    // You can decide what to do if the app hasn't mounted
    // You can ignore this, or add these actions to a queue you can call later
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this extensive answer. This is for React Navigation 5, am I correct? I would mark this as the correct answer, as React Navigation 5 is the current version and this is the best approach for today, but not sure how the Stack Overflow policy for such things is.

Comment: Yes, it is for Version: 5.x

Comment: Note that for Version 6.x, you should use ` import {  useNavigationContainerRef,
} from '@react-navigation/native';  ...... const navigationRef = useNavigationContainerRef();` instead of  ` React.createRef();` See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/ and https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container#ref